# Questions about using Z3Py online to solve problems in Transport Phenomena

Tags: z3

Certain problem in transport Phenomena is solved using the following code:

```
T_max, T_0, S, R, k, I, k_e, L, R, E, a = Reals('T_max T_0 S R k I k_e L R E a')
k = a*k_e*T_0
I = k_e*E/L
S = (I**2)/k_e
eq = T_0 + S* R**2/(4*k)
print eq
equations = [
T_max == eq,
]
print "Temperature equations:"
print equations
problem = [
R == 2, L == 5000,
T_0 == 20 + 273,
T_max   == 30 + 273, k_e == 1,
a == 2.23*10**(-8), E > 0
]
print "Problem:"
print problem 
print "Solution:"
solve(equations + problem)
```

using this code online we obtain

[image]

This output gives the correct answer but there are two issues in the code:  a)  the expresion named "eq" is not fully simplified and then it is necessary to give an arbitrary value for k_e .  My question is:   How to simplify the expression "eq" in such way that k_e be eliminated from "eq"?

Other example:  To determine the radius of a tube

Code:

```
def inte(n,a,b):
return (b**(n+1))/(n+1)-(a**(n+1))/(n+1)
P_0, P_1, L, R, mu, q, C = Reals('P_0 P_1 L R mu q C')
k = (P_0 - P_1)/(2*mu*L)
equations = [0 == -k*inte(1,0,R) +C,
q == 2*3.1416*(-(k/2)*inte(3,0,R) + C*inte(1,0,R))]
print "Fluid equations:"
print equations
problem = [
L == 50.02/100, mu == (4.03*10**(-5)),
P_0 == 4.829*10**5, P_1==0,
q   == 2.997*10**(-3), R >0
]
print "Problem:"
print problem 
print "Solution:"
solve(equations + problem)
```

Output:

```
Fluid equations:
[-((P_0 - P_1)/(2·mu·L))·(R2/2 - 0) + C = 0, q =
3927/625·
(-(((P_0 - P_1)/(2·mu·L))/2)·(R4/4 - 0) + C·(R2/2 - 0))]
Problem:
[L = 2501/5000, mu = 403/10000000, P_0 = 482900, P_1 = 0, q = 2997/1000000, R > 0]
Solution:
[R = 0.0007512843?,
q = 2997/1000000,
P_1 = 0,
P_0 = 482900,
mu = 403/10000000,
L = 2501/5000,
C = 3380.3149444289?]
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to constrain k_e != 0 instesad of k_e == 1?
This would be less restrictive on set of solutions that can be produced. Nevertheless, when running Z3 with this modified problem, I get the assignment k_e == 1. If you also add a constraint k_e != 1, Z3 finds indeed a different solution.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion but if the expression named "eq" is fully simplified the parameter K_e does not appear.  Do you know how to make such full simplification?

Comment: Juan, in Z3, `x/x == 1` only if `x != 0`. Moreover, even if we assert that `x != 0`, the current formula simplifier will not replace `x/x` with `1`. Similarly, it will not cancel the `k_e` in `(k_e^2 L^2)/k_e`. Note that, the procedure used in Z3 is not based on (full) simplification or simple algebraic simplifications. The simplifier is just a preprocessor for the real solver that is based on completely different techniques.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanations, in all case Z3 is wonderful.